# Unity3d - Can a package installation modify a project?

Tags: unity-game-engine, package

I would like to create a package that makes changes in the project when it is installed. like add a script to all colliders when the package is installed. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes this is possible. You could e.g. do it in [`InitializeOnLoad`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/InitializeOnLoadAttribute.html) or implement an [`AssetPostprocessor`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetPostprocessor.html) or [`AssetModificationProcessor`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetModificationProcessor.html) and there are probably a lot other options